# Terraform | The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks,

Tags: terraform, azure, terraform-module

I'm trying to upgrade out Terraform seeing as 0.12 (stable) came out recently. I've ran into some issues with a certain pair of resource blocks. I'm getting the below error message when trying to do terraform plan, if I remove the count index it gives me a different error and says that I need the count index but that gives this error:

```
The "count" object can be used only in "resource" and "data" blocks, and only
when the "count" argument is set.
```

Here is the terraform stripped down to only the relevant parts.

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "network_interface" {
    count                             = "${var.vm_server_count}"
    location                          = "${var.location}"
    }
}
Problematic resource block

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "network_interface" {
  network_interface_id    = "${azurerm_network_interface.network_interface[count.index]}"
  ip_configuration_name   = "example"
  backend_address_pool_id = "${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.network_interface.id}"
}
```

What am I missing here? This is Terraform 0.12 stable using Azure as the provider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "network_interface"` block doesn't have the `count` argument set, so `count.index` is not meaningful in that block.

Given the specific pair of resource types you're using here, I expect your intent was to create one association for each network interface, in which case you'd add the following `count` argument to the second block:

```
  count = length(azurerm_network_interface.network_interface)
```

Although this didn't return an error on Terraform 0.11, it did not behave as I expect you intended: it would've created only one `azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association` for the *first* network interface, and left the others unassociated.

---

If associating only the first one was your intent instead, then replace the `count.index` in the second block with `0` to be explicit that it's using only the first one:

```
  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.network_interface[0]
```

Comment: Thank you I ended up finding other stuff online related but this confirmed what I found